# Group content types together

Tags: 7, views

I have a view (table style) filtered three content types, added fields i want, but each type has a date field.

I needed to group all's nodes by date so i added a `Global: custom text` with replacement patterns i get what i need (one date field to three content types).

I grouped my view by this field but the problem is each content type has own table.

how can i group those three content types together in one table for every date value?

Comment: They really shouldn't be in separate tables... I've done this and my content types are all in one table.  Are you sure you haven't grouped by content type already to cause this behavior?

Comment: yes i did not grouped by content type, just by the date field i created.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I'm noticing this difference: when I don't set a field to sort by, my content types seem to be in separate tables too.

But if I set the 'Sort Criteria' to a field that all of the content types have, like 'Post date', desc, then I get all the content types correctly incorporated into one table:

[image]

Anyway, hope this helps you!